# Structure sharing Vector in Haskell

Tags: haskell, clojure

Is the `Vector` in Haskell structure sharing? In Clojure, modifying the (immutable) `vector` only takes O(log n) time because it is actually a trie-like structure. (http://hypirion.com/musings/understanding-persistent-vector-pt-1)

Is there an equivalent implementation in Haskell?

Comment: The `vector` library is implemented with arrays, and has clever rules for optimizing composed vector operations and provides a list-like API. Lots of haskell data structures are built on different sorts of trees, as you'd expect from a functional language, but I don't know about that particular construction.

Comment: Have a look at `Data.Sequence` at `http://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers-0.2.0.1/docs/Data-Sequence.html`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`Data.Vector` is plain arrays with O(n) modification.

At the time there is no equivalent of Clojure's vector.

`Data.Sequence` is implemented as a finger tree, and it supports a wider range of asymptotically efficient operations than Clojure's vector (O(log(n)) concatenation and splitting, O(1) read/write at both ends), but it's also a bit more heavyweight data structure with more RAM usage and some constant overheads.